# Filter array by date and value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying filter an array but it's returning empty, I'm trying to get it to return an array with where the date is in the previous 30 minutes and the value is over 15.

Let's say the current time is 19:45:

```
let transactions = [
  { value: "50.00", date: "2020-08-03T11:52:28.876Z" },
  { value: "13.10", date: "2020-08-03T11:57:32.900Z" },
  { value: "12.11", date: "2020-08-03T12:23:06.379Z" },
  { value: "12.89", date: "2020-08-03T14:20:41.720Z" },
  { value: "12.89", date: "2020-08-03T19:30:41.720Z" },
  { value: "22.89", date: "2020-08-03T19:34:41.720Z" },
  { value: "50.00", date: "2020-08-03T19:40:41.720Z" }
];

const THIRTY_MINUTES = 30 * 60 * 1000;

const isLastThirtyMins = transactions
  .map(
    transaction =>
      new Date().getTime() - new Date(transaction.date).getTime() <
      THIRTY_MINUTES
  )
  .filter(transaction => transaction.value >= 15);

console.log(isLastThirtyMins);
// []
```

I'm trying to get it to return these 2 items:

```
{ value: "22.89", date: "2020-08-03T19:34:41.720Z" }
{ value: "50.00", date: "2020-08-03T19:40:41.720Z" }
```

Comment: The call to `.map()` is going to create an array of boolean values. You don't need `.map()` at all, and you need to do **both** comparisons in the `.filter()` callback.

Comment: Why is the value a string? It'd be easier to manipulate if it were a `Number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filter instead of map

```js
const isLastThirtyMins = transactions
  .filter(transaction => new Date().getTime() - new Date(transaction.date).getTime() < THIRTY_MINUTES)
  .filter(transaction => parseFloat(transaction.value) >= 15);
```

Or better, call filter only once:

```js
const isLastThirtyMins = transactions
  .filter(transaction =>
    (new Date().getTime() - new Date(transaction.date).getTime() < THIRTY_MINUTES) &&
    (parseFloat(transaction.value) >= 15));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const isLastThirtyMins = transactions
  .filter(
    transaction =>
      new Date().getTime() - new Date(transaction.date).getTime() <
      THIRTY_MINUTES
  );
```

Exaplaination:

What you where doing is mapping each element in you array to `new Date().getTime() - new Date(transaction.date).getTime() < THIRTY_MINUTES` which is a `boolean`. Thus, the return value of `map` would be something like `[true, false, false, true ...]` and then you are trying to filter this returned array by `transaction.value`, but as you can see, `transaction` now is a boolean and not the real transaction and it does not have `value` property.